# Are related records loaded into HashSet or SortedSet?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Assume we have POCO class for Entity Framework 4:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

And this method to retrieve the order from database:

```
public Order GetOrder(long orderId)
{
    using (var context = new MyModelEntities())
    {
        return context.Orders.Include("OrderItems").Where(order => order.Id == orderId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So suppose we do this:

```
Order myOrder = GetOrder(1);
```

Is myOrder.OrderItems a HashSet or SortedSet? Is there a way to control this?

Comment: by the way, i assume `public long ISet<OrderItem>` is a typo? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

As far as i know (and there is no MSDN/blog/article i am aware of that dispells/proves this), a navigational property can be of any type as long as it implements `ICollection<T>`.

Both `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>` implement `ICollection<T>`, so either would be viable candidates.

Did you step through the code? You should be able to see which concrete class get's resolved.

Most people use `ICollection<T>` / `IList<T>`. Why are you wanting to declare the property as `ISet<T>`?

Why don't you just declare which type you want, instead of the interface.

Or you could try using dependency injection (`For<ISet>().Use<HashSet>()`).

Comment: Excellent advice to check the type when debugging. Not sure why I haven't thought of it.. It seems that by default EF4 will use HashSet over SortedSet. Also interestingly, when I changed to IList<T> everything worked just fine. So I guess there is a lot of reflection being used by EF4, as in to what is the type of the class property and it declares an instance based on that.

Would be nice to see an article explaining the inner-workings of this.

Comment: @niaher - agreed. It's not like MVC where we can view the source. :) I know a lot of EF POCO is convention based. I personally just use `ICollection<T>`.